# Excel Power Query Merge and Transform columns

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to combine 2 columns into one and then replace "Null" rows with the value in an adjacent columns using Excel Power Query. SO far I haven't been able to resolve this issue.
These are my unsuccessful attempts:

Attempt 1:

```
= Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "F 52 AGR_1016", {"AGR_NAME"}, {"F 52 AGR_1016.AGR_NAME"}),
 else Table.ReplaceValue(Source, each "", Replacer.ReplaceValue{"New value of line"})
```

Attempt 2:

```
= Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "F 52 AGR_1016", {"AGR_NAME"}, {"F 52 AGR_1016.AGR_NAME"}), 
if #"F 52 AGR_1016" = "" then Replacer.ReplaceValue("","",{"New Value of line"}), else
```

I get the following error message, however Excel does not show me where exactly that error is:

Expression.SyntaxError: Token Eof expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to tell what you are doing, and the code format is incorrect. You can't append **if then** to **Table.ExpandTableColumn**

To merge two column: click select them, right click, then choose **merge columns**

To add a column that tests other column values, add column .. custom column ... and use = if xxx then yyy else zzz

```
= if [Col1] = null then [Col2] else [Col3]
```

This code expands three columns; merges the text value of Column1 and Column2 into a new column called Merged; creates Column4 where the result is Merge if Column3 is a null, and Column3 if Column3 is not a null

```
...
#"Expanded" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "AllRows", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Expanded",{"Column2", "Column1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom4", each if [Column3]=null then [Merged] else [Column3])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! Using your code I ended up using a simple if then statement.What I was trying to do is in order to keep the number of columns low is to merge 2 columns and then fill out the remaining blanks. Now I have 2 columns for that, but since it works I'll leave it like that.